# ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/Firebase/Core/FIRBundleUtil.m:17:9: fatal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

Trying to compile my project after adding some pods. While compiling it gives below error

> ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/Firebase/Core/FIRBundleUtil.m:17:9: fatal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found

Podfile.lock snippet

```
PODS:
  - Firebase/Auth (5.20.2):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (= 5.4.2)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (5.20.2):
    - FirebaseCore (= 5.4.1)
  - FirebaseAuth (5.4.2):
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 5.2)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
  - FirebaseCore (5.4.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 5.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 5.2)
  - GoogleMaps (2.7.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Maps (= 2.7.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Base (2.7.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Maps (2.7.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Base
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (5.8.0)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (5.8.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.2.2)
  - OneSignal (2.10.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Firebase/Auth (~> 5.0)
  - GoogleMaps (~> 2.7.0)
  - OneSignal (= 2.10.0)

SPEC REPOS:
  https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git:
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAuth
    - FirebaseAuthInterop
    - FirebaseCore
    - GoogleMaps
    - GoogleUtilities
    - GTMSessionFetcher
    - OneSignal

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Firebase: 0c8cf33f266410c61ab3e2265cfa412200351d9c
  FirebaseAuth: dd7bbf03a5aee0eafb3a1aee4d2812bd74bac890
  FirebaseAuthInterop: 0ffa57668be100582bb7643d4fcb7615496c41fc
  FirebaseCore: f1a9a8be1aee4bf71a2fc0f4096df6788bdfda61
  GoogleMaps: f79af95cb24d869457b1f961c93d3ce8b2f3b848
  GoogleUtilities: 04fce34bcd5620c1ee76fb79172105c74a4df335
  GTMSessionFetcher: 61bb0f61a4cb560030f1222021178008a5727a23
  OneSignal: 0f5ff711d9f25da54885e4ab06ef0abc221a46ef

PODFILE CHECKSUM: cf31b8292942542e2263db4df5cb6213477ea329

COCOAPODS: 1.7.5
```

`pod update` does not help

Comment: Try `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help